# Is the macro _STRING_ for C++ header <string> defined in the standard?

Tags: c++, header-files, std

There's this macro `_STRING_` defined in Visual C++ 2013's header `<string>`.

Is this macro defined in the C++ standard or just platform-specific?

Is there a standard preprocessing way to know whether a standard library header is included?

Edit:
I just searched the C++11 standard. There's no match for `_STRING_`. So the first question seems to have negative answer.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to check this?  Can't you just include `<string>` yourself, then you know it has been included.

Comment: It might be helpful to say what you want to do, and then others can see if there is a portable way to do what you want

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum: All standard header files lead to a portable way.

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum Say I have defined a function that takes in `char const * data, std::size_t size`. I want to define an overloaded wrapper function for `std::string` if it is included, but I don't want to always include `<string>` to do that. Just trying to keep the header size small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not defined in the C++ standard, but names beginning with an underscore and a capital letter are reserved for the implementation, so shouldn't be used in your code.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a standard preprocessing way to know whether a standard library header is included?

Nope.  If you're trying to [identify redundant #includes](https://www.google.com/search?q=identify%20redundant%20#include), there's lots of ways, I'd say external tools is right for meta-tests like that.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this macro defined in the C++ standard or just platform-specific?

No. It's compiler specific.

> Is there a standard preprocessing way to know whether a standard library header is included?

No.